# Append an element to particular list within a list - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, arraylist

```
child= [[]] * 10
child[0].append(3)
```

I expected the output to be

```
child
[[3], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

where output came out to be

```
child
[[3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3]]
```

Comment: duplicate of the ca 1000 questions related to lists of identical objects: your `child` contains the *same* list ten times. Not ten different lists.

Comment: Thanks @MarcusMüller . That clarifies my doubt !